# 'Another two' or 'Two more'?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Two guards stepped out of the elevator. Another two/Two more stepped out of the stairwell. And together the four of them moved down the hall.

Can either "another two" and "two more" be used here?

Comment: Either one is perfectly acceptable in this context

Answer (score 1):

"Another two" and "two more" mean the same thing, and both are acceptable in this case. I prefer "two more", as it echoes the pattern of "two guards" in the first sentence.

Comment: "Two more" is more widely used. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+two%2C+two+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canother%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20more%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Canother%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20more%3B%2Cc0